How to Wake Up the Screen in BroadcastReceiver After PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK Deprecation?
I'm working on an Android app where I need to wake up the device screen when an alarm is triggered. Previously, I used PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK to achieve this, but it has been deprecated.
The way I used to wake up the screen:
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "CrmAlarmReceiver::WakeLock");
    try {
        wakeLock.acquire(5000); // 5 seconds
        // Your existing code...
    } finally {
        if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
            wakeLock.release();
        }
    }

I found this approach but I need to extend Activity to use the getWindow(), so while my AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver it doesnt work.
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

Here is what I tried:

Using getWindow() in BroadcastReceiver:
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    int eventId = intent.getIntExtra("eventId", 0);

    String comments = intent.getStringExtra("comments");

    String alarmTitle = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    NOTIFICATION_ID = eventId;  
  context.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);             context.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);               context.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);            context.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

}


Starting a new activity with the flags set, but the activity does
not run the code.
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);

activityIntent.putExtra("eventId", eventId);

activityIntent.putExtra("comments", comments);

activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

context.startActivity(activityIntent);




   public class WakeScreenActivity extends Activity {
   
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wake_screen);   
        new Handler().postDelayed(this::finish, 5000);
    }}


Setting as fullscreenintent an intent that has the above code
inside.
private PendingIntent createFullScreenIntent(Context context, int eventId, String comments) {
Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(context, WakeScreenActivity.class);
fullScreenIntent.putExtra("eventId", eventId);
fullScreenIntent.putExtra("comments", comments);
return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);    }



What is the recommended approach for waking up the screen and ensuring it is visible when an alarm is triggered, given the deprecation of PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK?
Target SDK version: 34
Minimum SDK version: 21
